# Object seen as string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

In my code, i have the response from a PHP database in a variable. It should be an objet however when I console log typeof variable, it return "string". When i console.log the variable itself and copy paste it in my code (as a variable "test") then console.log(typeof test) it return object and i can manipulate "test" normaly... I dont understand why beacause logically it should act the same way. 
Is there a way to transfom the "string" type variable into a "object" type ? 
Thank you in advance (you can see my code below)

```
var div = document.getElementById("dom");
var variable= div.textContent;
var test = [{"num":"1","ID":"1","statut":"telecharge",{"num":"2","ID":"400","statut":"telecharge"}]
console.log(variable)
console.log(typeof variable)
```

Comment: JSON.parse(response) to convert a stringified object into object

Answer (score 1):

The `textContent` of an element will *always* return a string, no matter what the content is. If you have something that's valid JSON as the `textContent` of an element, you can turn it into an object with `JSON.parse`:

```js
const div = document.getElementById("dom");
const json = div.textContent;
const arr = JSON.parse(json);
for (const { num } of arr) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<div id="dom">[{"num":"1","ID":"1","statut":"telecharge" },{"num":"2","ID":"400","statut":"telecharge"}]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP outputs plain text with some headers that suggest what type of output it is (HTML/JSON)

Now with your situation, you need to `JSON.parse(response)` to convert JSON string to JS Object

Answer (score 0):

The response from php is "string". So, you have to parse it, let you are getting response in a variable named " response then do the following and check:
var response = ;
var resObj = JSON.parse(response);
Now, check this resObj.

I think you are very new to JavaScript, So I am just showing you, your code with small changes for your better understanding and solution. Must read the comments, they help you to understand reasons.

```html
<html>
 <body>
 
 <div id="dom">[{"num":"1","ID":"1","statut":"telecharge" },{"num":"2","ID":"400","statut":"telecharge"}]</div>

 <script>
 var div = document.getElementById("dom");
 var variable= div.textContent;
 
 //Here, It is parse string to JSON (object)
 var test = JSON.parse(variable);
 
 //Here it is string because you just fetch text (datatype string) from div
 console.log(variable)
 console.log(typeof variable)
 
 //So, here its data type is object
 console.log(test)
 console.log(typeof test)
 
 </script>
 </body>

</html>
```